# Android x86 ping fails

Tags: vmware, android-x86

I managed to run and install android x86 4.0 RC1 in VMWare. The problem however is that I have no internet.

I went to the console and ran `netcfg eth0 dhcp`. Eth0 then gets a valid IP address but when running ping the host doesn't exists. (`ping google.com`) So I pinged the router which responded correctly. Some posts suggest to add the DNS by either `setprop net.eth0.dns1 dnsip` or `setprop net.dns1 dnsip`. I test both but with no result.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

BTW,

- The VM is configured to use NAT.
- When using bridged (which is recommend by some) the dhcp action fails

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have either figured this out or moved on, but when I had this happen I would set the DNS to use Google's public DNS servers.  This seemed to work for me.

```
setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
```